# Getting number of days between dates - SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, date-arithmetic

```
CREATE TABLE Employee(
   EmployeeID NUMBER,
   LastName varchar(100),
   FirstName varchar(100),
   Address varchar2(100),
   varchar(100),
   City varchar(100),
   State varchar(100),
   Zip varchar(7),
   StartDate DATE,
   EndDate DATE
);
```

I have Created a table in SQL and I need to count the days between StartDate and EndDate. I have tried using DATEDIFF but it does not work.

Comment: Your CREATE TABLE, as shown, will not execute.  What's with that extra VARCHAR2 between ADDRESS and CITY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle has straight-forward date arithmetics: what you ask for is as simple as just substracting the dates:

```
select e.*, enddate - startdate days_diff
from employee e
```

This gives you a numeric value that represents the number of days. You can remove the decimal part with `floor()` if you want an integer value:

```
select e.*, floor(enddate - startdate) days_diff
from employee e
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you, much appreciated!